# How to autopopulate the body of an email with values from a table found by using the Worksheet_Change Function

Tags: excel, vba, email

I am creating an inventory spreadsheet. When the quantity of a part goes below the reorder quantity, there is an auto popup with an email to send to reorder the part.

The code is identifying when to pop up with an email, but I wan't to autofill the email with the part number and vendor information.

My table lists Part Number first, then description, then vendor, then quantity, then reorder quantity.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim xRg As Range
    
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Set xRg = Intersect(Range("I5:I100"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value <= Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target.Value, Sheets("Inventory List").Range("I5:J52"), 2, False) Then
        Call EmailAdmin(Target.Value)
    End If
End Sub

Sub EmailAdmin(Target)
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String

   Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Part needs to be reordered" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
      "Part Number: " & vbNewLine & _
      "Description:  " & vbNewLine & _
      "Vendor:  "

    On Error Resume Next
    user = Environ("Username ")
    With xOutMail
        .To = "Admin"
        .CC = user + "@gmail.com"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Equipment/Reagents Needed"

        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display 'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

The EmailAdmin sub does not appear if there is an attempt to pass arguments.
[image]

Comment: What is in column I? Sounds like you need `target.offset(,1)` or similar.

Comment: That is my column that lists the quantity. It is just detecting change in quantity. I am more concerned that I can't pass that target value into my email sub. So the email doesn't know which row of information to pull from

Comment: Your sub doesn't have any arguments.

Comment: I know, because when I try to add arguments to it, it won't run

Comment: Post your attempt please.

Comment: I will edit my original code to show you the attempt and what happens when I try to run.

Comment: That should run but you don't actually refer to `Target` in the sub. You need to pass several arguments also.

Comment: And subs with parameters don't appear in the list, they can only be run from another sub whence you pass the arguments.

Comment: Ohhh, okay I see. Sorry, I am very new to VBA and do not know much about it. What other arguments would I need to pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your Subs simple. THe Email-Sub should not need to know where the data is - so pass it as arguments from the sub that knows where the data is...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  ...
  Call EmailAdmin(Target.offset(0,1).value,Target.offset(0,2).value,Target.offset(0,2).value)
  ...
End Sub

Sub EmailAdmin(PartNr, Description, Vendor)
  ...
    xMailBody = "Part needs to be reordered" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Part Number: " & PartNr & vbNewLine & _
    "Description:  " & Description & vbNewLine & _
    "Vendor:  " & Vendor
  ...
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you sooo much for taking the time to help me. This was so clear and concise. I really really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad its of use. When the answer solves your problem, please always mark it as solved. Cheers